# Stylegan2 Tensorflow training interrupts after a a minute in Google Colab

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, generative-adversarial-network

I am trying to train a stylegan2 model in Google Colab. I have been the following [stylegan2-colab](https://github.com/parthsuresh/stylegan2-colab) notebook. However, when I try to train the model it suddenly stops. As you can see in the end of the output, it seems like a keyboard interruptions (`^C`), so I am wondering whether it could be a ram issue. At one point when it crashed, it asked me if I wanted to increase the ram limit, which I did. I initially tried with 1028x1028 images, but have not switched to 256x256, which didn't help. Any idea what might be going on?

```
!python run_training.py --data-dir='/content/drive/My Drive/kaggle/datasets' \
    --config=config-f --dataset=abstract-256 --result-dir='/content/drive/My Drive/kaggle/snapshots'
```

###Output

```
Local submit - run_dir: /content/drive/My Drive/kaggle/snapshots/00006-stylegan2-abstract-256-1gpu-config-f
dnnlib: Running training.training_loop.training_loop() on localhost...
Streaming data using training.dataset.TFRecordDataset...
tcmalloc: large alloc 4294967296 bytes == 0x866e000 @  0x7fea77378001 0x7fea73dc4765 0x7fea73e28dc0 0x7fea73e2ac5f 0x7fea73ec1238 0x50ac25 0x50d390 0x508245 0x509642 0x595311 0x54a6ff 0x551b81 0x5a067e 0x50d966 0x508245 0x58958c 0x5a067e 0x50d966 0x508245 0x58958c 0x5a067e 0x50d966 0x509d48 0x50aa7d 0x50c5b9 0x509d48 0x50aa7d 0x50c5b9 0x508245 0x58958c 0x5a067e
tcmalloc: large alloc 4294967296 bytes == 0x7fe8c8066000 @  0x7fea773761e7 0x7fea73dc45e1 0x7fea73e28e88 0x7fea73e29147 0x7fea73ec1118 0x50ac25 0x50d390 0x508245 0x50a080 0x50aa7d 0x50d390 0x508245 0x50a080 0x50aa7d 0x50d390 0x508245 0x50a080 0x50aa7d 0x50d390 0x509d48 0x50aa7d 0x50c5b9 0x508245 0x50a080 0x50aa7d 0x50c5b9 0x508245 0x50a080 0x50aa7d 0x50d390 0x508245
tcmalloc: large alloc 4294967296 bytes == 0x7fe7c7864000 @  0x7fea773761e7 0x7fea73dc45e1 0x7fea73e28e88 0x7fea73e29147 0x7fea3a604f05 0x7fea39f88742 0x7fea39f88cf2 0x7fea39f41a7e 0x50a8af 0x50c5b9 0x509d48 0x50aa7d 0x50c5b9 0x508245 0x5893bb 0x5a067e 0x50d966 0x508245 0x50a080 0x50aa7d 0x50c5b9 0x508245 0x50a080 0x50aa7d 0x50c5b9 0x509d48 0x50aa7d 0x50c5b9 0x508245 0x509642 0x595311
Dataset shape = [3, 256, 256]
Dynamic range = [0, 255]
Label size    = 0
Loading networks from "/content/stylegan2-ffhq-config-f.pkl"...
Setting up TensorFlow plugin "fused_bias_act.cu": Preprocessing... Compiling... Loading... Done.
Setting up TensorFlow plugin "upfirdn_2d.cu": Preprocessing... Compiling... Loading... Done.

G                               Params    OutputShape          WeightShape     
---                             ---       ---                  ---             
latents_in                      -         (?, 512)             -               
labels_in                       -         (?, 0)               -               
lod                             -         ()                   -               
dlatent_avg                     -         (512,)               -               
G_mapping/latents_in            -         (?, 512)             -               
G_mapping/labels_in             -         (?, 0)               -               
G_mapping/Normalize             -         (?, 512)             -               
G_mapping/Dense0                262656    (?, 512)             (512, 512)      
G_mapping/Dense1                262656    (?, 512)             (512, 512)      
G_mapping/Dense2                262656    (?, 512)             (512, 512)      
G_mapping/Dense3                262656    (?, 512)             (512, 512)      
G_mapping/Dense4                262656    (?, 512)             (512, 512)      
G_mapping/Dense5                262656    (?, 512)             (512, 512)      
G_mapping/Dense6                262656    (?, 512)             (512, 512)      
G_mapping/Dense7                262656    (?, 512)             (512, 512)      
G_mapping/Broadcast             -         (?, 18, 512)         -               
G_mapping/dlatents_out          -         (?, 18, 512)         -               
Truncation/Lerp                 -         (?, 18, 512)         -               
G_synthesis/dlatents_in         -         (?, 18, 512)         -               
G_synthesis/4x4/Const           8192      (?, 512, 4, 4)       (1, 512, 4, 4)  
G_synthesis/4x4/Conv            2622465   (?, 512, 4, 4)       (3, 3, 512, 512)
G_synthesis/4x4/ToRGB           264195    (?, 3, 4, 4)         (1, 1, 512, 3)  
G_synthesis/8x8/Conv0_up        2622465   (?, 512, 8, 8)       (3, 3, 512, 512)
G_synthesis/8x8/Conv1           2622465   (?, 512, 8, 8)       (3, 3, 512, 512)
G_synthesis/8x8/Upsample        -         (?, 3, 8, 8)         -               
G_synthesis/8x8/ToRGB           264195    (?, 3, 8, 8)         (1, 1, 512, 3)  
G_synthesis/16x16/Conv0_up      2622465   (?, 512, 16, 16)     (3, 3, 512, 512)
G_synthesis/16x16/Conv1         2622465   (?, 512, 16, 16)     (3, 3, 512, 512)
G_synthesis/16x16/Upsample      -         (?, 3, 16, 16)       -               
G_synthesis/16x16/ToRGB         264195    (?, 3, 16, 16)       (1, 1, 512, 3)  
G_synthesis/32x32/Conv0_up      2622465   (?, 512, 32, 32)     (3, 3, 512, 512)
G_synthesis/32x32/Conv1         2622465   (?, 512, 32, 32)     (3, 3, 512, 512)
G_synthesis/32x32/Upsample      -         (?, 3, 32, 32)       -               
G_synthesis/32x32/ToRGB         264195    (?, 3, 32, 32)       (1, 1, 512, 3)  
G_synthesis/64x64/Conv0_up      2622465   (?, 512, 64, 64)     (3, 3, 512, 512)
G_synthesis/64x64/Conv1         2622465   (?, 512, 64, 64)     (3, 3, 512, 512)
G_synthesis/64x64/Upsample      -         (?, 3, 64, 64)       -               
G_synthesis/64x64/ToRGB         264195    (?, 3, 64, 64)       (1, 1, 512, 3)  
G_synthesis/128x128/Conv0_up    1442561   (?, 256, 128, 128)   (3, 3, 512, 256)
G_synthesis/128x128/Conv1       721409    (?, 256, 128, 128)   (3, 3, 256, 256)
G_synthesis/128x128/Upsample    -         (?, 3, 128, 128)     -               
G_synthesis/128x128/ToRGB       132099    (?, 3, 128, 128)     (1, 1, 256, 3)  
G_synthesis/256x256/Conv0_up    426369    (?, 128, 256, 256)   (3, 3, 256, 128)
G_synthesis/256x256/Conv1       213249    (?, 128, 256, 256)   (3, 3, 128, 128)
G_synthesis/256x256/Upsample    -         (?, 3, 256, 256)     -               
G_synthesis/256x256/ToRGB       66051     (?, 3, 256, 256)     (1, 1, 128, 3)  
G_synthesis/512x512/Conv0_up    139457    (?, 64, 512, 512)    (3, 3, 128, 64) 
G_synthesis/512x512/Conv1       69761     (?, 64, 512, 512)    (3, 3, 64, 64)  
G_synthesis/512x512/Upsample    -         (?, 3, 512, 512)     -               
G_synthesis/512x512/ToRGB       33027     (?, 3, 512, 512)     (1, 1, 64, 3)   
G_synthesis/1024x1024/Conv0_up  51297     (?, 32, 1024, 1024)  (3, 3, 64, 32)  
G_synthesis/1024x1024/Conv1     25665     (?, 32, 1024, 1024)  (3, 3, 32, 32)  
G_synthesis/1024x1024/Upsample  -         (?, 3, 1024, 1024)   -               
G_synthesis/1024x1024/ToRGB     16515     (?, 3, 1024, 1024)   (1, 1, 32, 3)   
G_synthesis/images_out          -         (?, 3, 1024, 1024)   -               
G_synthesis/noise0              -         (1, 1, 4, 4)         -               
G_synthesis/noise1              -         (1, 1, 8, 8)         -               
G_synthesis/noise2              -         (1, 1, 8, 8)         -               
G_synthesis/noise3              -         (1, 1, 16, 16)       -               
G_synthesis/noise4              -         (1, 1, 16, 16)       -               
G_synthesis/noise5              -         (1, 1, 32, 32)       -               
G_synthesis/noise6              -         (1, 1, 32, 32)       -               
G_synthesis/noise7              -         (1, 1, 64, 64)       -               
G_synthesis/noise8              -         (1, 1, 64, 64)       -               
G_synthesis/noise9              -         (1, 1, 128, 128)     -               
G_synthesis/noise10             -         (1, 1, 128, 128)     -               
G_synthesis/noise11             -         (1, 1, 256, 256)     -               
G_synthesis/noise12             -         (1, 1, 256, 256)     -               
G_synthesis/noise13             -         (1, 1, 512, 512)     -               
G_synthesis/noise14             -         (1, 1, 512, 512)     -               
G_synthesis/noise15             -         (1, 1, 1024, 1024)   -               
G_synthesis/noise16             -         (1, 1, 1024, 1024)   -               
images_out                      -         (?, 3, 1024, 1024)   -               
---                             ---       ---                  ---             
Total                           30370060                                       


D                     Params    OutputShape          WeightShape     
---                   ---       ---                  ---             
images_in             -         (?, 3, 1024, 1024)   -               
labels_in             -         (?, 0)               -               
1024x1024/FromRGB     128       (?, 32, 1024, 1024)  (1, 1, 3, 32)   
1024x1024/Conv0       9248      (?, 32, 1024, 1024)  (3, 3, 32, 32)  
1024x1024/Conv1_down  18496     (?, 64, 512, 512)    (3, 3, 32, 64)  
1024x1024/Skip        2048      (?, 64, 512, 512)    (1, 1, 32, 64)  
512x512/Conv0         36928     (?, 64, 512, 512)    (3, 3, 64, 64)  
512x512/Conv1_down    73856     (?, 128, 256, 256)   (3, 3, 64, 128) 
512x512/Skip          8192      (?, 128, 256, 256)   (1, 1, 64, 128) 
256x256/Conv0         147584    (?, 128, 256, 256)   (3, 3, 128, 128)
256x256/Conv1_down    295168    (?, 256, 128, 128)   (3, 3, 128, 256)
256x256/Skip          32768     (?, 256, 128, 128)   (1, 1, 128, 256)
128x128/Conv0         590080    (?, 256, 128, 128)   (3, 3, 256, 256)
128x128/Conv1_down    1180160   (?, 512, 64, 64)     (3, 3, 256, 512)
128x128/Skip          131072    (?, 512, 64, 64)     (1, 1, 256, 512)
64x64/Conv0           2359808   (?, 512, 64, 64)     (3, 3, 512, 512)
64x64/Conv1_down      2359808   (?, 512, 32, 32)     (3, 3, 512, 512)
64x64/Skip            262144    (?, 512, 32, 32)     (1, 1, 512, 512)
32x32/Conv0           2359808   (?, 512, 32, 32)     (3, 3, 512, 512)
32x32/Conv1_down      2359808   (?, 512, 16, 16)     (3, 3, 512, 512)
32x32/Skip            262144    (?, 512, 16, 16)     (1, 1, 512, 512)
16x16/Conv0           2359808   (?, 512, 16, 16)     (3, 3, 512, 512)
16x16/Conv1_down      2359808   (?, 512, 8, 8)       (3, 3, 512, 512)
16x16/Skip            262144    (?, 512, 8, 8)       (1, 1, 512, 512)
8x8/Conv0             2359808   (?, 512, 8, 8)       (3, 3, 512, 512)
8x8/Conv1_down        2359808   (?, 512, 4, 4)       (3, 3, 512, 512)
8x8/Skip              262144    (?, 512, 4, 4)       (1, 1, 512, 512)
4x4/MinibatchStddev   -         (?, 513, 4, 4)       -               
4x4/Conv              2364416   (?, 512, 4, 4)       (3, 3, 513, 512)
4x4/Dense0            4194816   (?, 512)             (8192, 512)     
Output                513       (?, 1)               (512, 1)        
scores_out            -         (?, 1)               -               
---                   ---       ---                  ---             
Total                 29012513                                       

tcmalloc: large alloc 6039797760 bytes == 0x7fe5719e2000 @  0x7fea773761e7 0x7fea73dc45e1 0x7fea73e28e88 0x7fea73e29147 0x7fea73ec1118 0x50ac25 0x50c5b9 0x508245 0x50a080 0x50aa7d 0x50c5b9 0x508245 0x50a080 0x50aa7d 0x50d390 0x508245 0x58958c 0x5a067e 0x50d966 0x509d48 0x50aa7d 0x50c5b9 0x509d48 0x50aa7d 0x50c5b9 0x508245 0x58958c 0x5a067e 0x50d966 0x508245 0x58958c
tcmalloc: large alloc 6039797760 bytes == 0x7fe3f6a56000 @  0x7fea77378001 0x7fea73dc4765 0x7fea73e28dc0 0x7fea73e2ac5f 0x7fea73ec1238 0x50ac25 0x50d390 0x508245 0x50a080 0x50aa7d 0x50c5b9 0x508245 0x50a080 0x50aa7d 0x50d390 0x508245 0x58958c 0x5a067e 0x50d966 0x509d48 0x50aa7d 0x50c5b9 0x509d48 0x50aa7d 0x50c5b9 0x508245 0x58958c 0x5a067e 0x50d966 0x508245 0x58958c
tcmalloc: large alloc 6039797760 bytes == 0x7fe28ea56000 @  0x7fea773761e7 0x7fea73dc45e1 0x7fea73e28e88 0x7fea73e28fa3 0x7fea73edc1dd 0x7fea73edcb3e 0x7fea73edf4b8 0x7fea7401f466 0x7fea74020f34 0x7fea74023682 0x7fea740244fe 0x5a522c 0x5a58f8 0x7fea73ee725b 0x5a18f5 0x50d76e 0x509d48 0x50aa7d 0x50c5b9 0x508245 0x50a080 0x50aa7d 0x50c5b9 0x508245 0x50a080 0x50aa7d 0x50d390 0x508245 0x58958c 0x5a067e 0x50d966
^C
```

Comment: It seems like it is due to Colab running out of memory (you only get 12.72 GB on a free instance). I saw it go critical before the `^C` appears. I tried lowering the `--total-kimg` parameter down to as low as 10 and it still happens. Did you ever find a fix for this? The repo's readme says that you need a GPU with at least 16 GB of RAM but I'm not sure if that is what Colab reports on, or if it is system RAM

Comment: Good point! I haven’t found a solution yet, but I think having the colabs subscription might work.

Comment: I just tried scaling down all my images to 64x64 and setting `--total-kimg=10` and it still failed, but gets further. It is definitely a memory issue. It could be that this model is just too much for CoLab to handle, otherwise a memory leak, but I wouldn't know where to start looking for evidence of that.

Comment: Yeah I did the same. Are you using Colab Pro?

Comment: No, just regular

Comment: If its memory issue on colab, use this colab  link https://colab.research.google.com/drive/155S_bb3viIoL0wAwkIyr1r8XQu4ARwA9?usp=sharing to double memory from 12.7 GB to 25 GB. And try executing your code. Thanks

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

1. Reduce the minibatch value in train script
2. Try to use another pretrained model, for instance,
   **stylegan2-church-config-f.pkl**

> ```
> Loading networks from "/content/stylegan2-ffhq-config-f.pkl"...
> ```

3. Try different config – config-e